# How to pass token from openID connect provider to AppSync api

Tags: amazon-web-services, openid-connect, openid, aws-appsync

I have set up AppSync to use OIDC / OpenID Connect as authoriser and have gotten token on client successfully. I am not using cognito. I am now trying to figure out following:

1. I am using apollo sdk to interact with my AppSync GraphQL api, how do I pass this open id token from client to it? I assume it has to be some sort of header, but I am unable to find any docs on what AppSync expects it to be.
2. Once I pass the token, how do I access its claims in AppSync / AppSync resolver, after it has been verified and token data extracted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Pass the Firebase token when you create the client:

```
const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
  url: ...,
  region: ...,
  auth: {
    type: 'OPENID_CONNECT',
    jwtToken: async() => token // Token from Firebase
  }
})
```

2. The claims from the token are available in `$context.identity` . Some of these claims are standard claims (specified by OpenID Connect) and others are custom claims (unique to your project). The shape of `$context.identity` will be similar to one emitted had you used AWS Cognito instead of Firebase:

```
{
    "sub" : "...", // standard claim - straight from the token
    "issuer" : "...", // standard claim - straight from the token
    "username" : "...",
    "claims" : { ... }, // custom claims from the token
    "sourceIp" : ["x.x.x.x"],
    "defaultAuthStrategy" : "..."
}
```

As you can see above, `sub` and `iss` are two standard claims that are mapped directly from the token. All other claims from the token are surfaced as custom claims. They can be retrieved via `$context.identity.claims.get()`

You could then use these claims in a resolver and [act on them in a standard fashion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security.html#fine-grained-access-control).